# LDAP connector doesn't read parameter

Tags: ldap, wso2-esb

I have an issue during the execution time and I believe that the connector maybe has a problem with its parameters for [ldap.init](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+LDAP+Operations). During the execution of this component an error is gotten by the fault flow:

```
[2016-04-22 18:08:24,089]  INFO - LogMediator To: /SampleContextLdapContext, MessageID: urn:uuid:bd9a9e05-84eb-48d9-8cef-6eff06b6f64d, Direction: request, DEUPAU = An error has been gotten, messageFaultError = Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator, messageFaultCode = 0, messageFaultException = , messageFaultDetail = org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:82)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:129)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:78)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:378)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:363)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.connector.ldap.Authenticate.connect(Authenticate.java:55)
    at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
    ... 22 more
```

It seems that I missed some parameter as the error occurs in Authenticate.java. Look at [line 55 in the GitHub](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-ldap/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/connector/ldap/Authenticate.java#L55) and now on a part of my XML:

```
<api context="/SampleContextLdapContext" name="SampleLdapName" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="POST" protocol="http">
    <inSequence>
      <log description="" separator=",">
        <property name="Message Flow" value="LDAP SAMPLE TEST"/>
        <property expression="//myvar/text()" name="myVarValue"/>
      </log>
      <ldap.init>
        <providerUrl>ldap://192.168.2.10:389/</providerUrl>
        <securityPrincipal>aqlbras\willian</securityPrincipal>
        <securityCredentials>SamplePassword</securityCredentials>
      </ldap.init>
```

When I don't configure **providerUrl** the error occurs at line 54, it means that the name parameter is correct for this tag but it's incorrect for **securityPrincipal** tag (you can see in GitHub repository to make sure).

Have I missed something or there is a mistake in the code?

---

### Requirement details

- Create a rest web service which receives an username and password.
- Use the parameters to authenticate in a LDAP directory and return some of his own attributes/properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your securityPrincipal is not an LDAP distinguished name (DN). For example, it would look something like `uid=willian,ou=people,dc=aqlbras,dc=com`

I am not surprised that you get a NullPointerException if you do not set the providerUrl. This is basically the hostname/port information to your LDAP server.

Comment: There is no problem connecting using "domain\username". It works as expected and I tested through LDAP Browser and JXplorer. I pointed out the _NullPointerException_ to clarify the problem about the parameter. The LDAP component does not recognize the securityPrincipal property, if so the _NullPointException_ shouldn't be raised.

Thank you for your attempt to answer the question, but my problem is about the *LDAP component and its issues*, not the communication with a LDAP server.

Comment: Your client may accept "domain\username" format, but that is not standard LDAP DN. You client may be using some form of SASL bind that is not present in JNDI (via WSO2). You can determine the DN of the user from your client if you navigate to the user entry and look at the "DN" attribute.

Comment: I totally agree with you and that's even important to be available here, but my issue is about the WSO2 ESB and LDAP component.

Comment: Well, WSO2 ESB is using standard JNDI (and the JNDI LDAP provider) under the covers. I really don't see what you can do here other than providing a DN.

Comment: It does not matter. **Whatever** the value I insert in securityPrincipal the NullPointerException is raised. The application didn't even try to connect with the LDAP Server. It's pretty straightforward until here.

Comment: If I read the WSO ESB LDAP connector properly (and the Authenticate class that you referenced in your original post), the bind DN parameter comes from the "dn" parameter - see https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-ldap/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/connector/ldap/Authenticate.java#L44 . Did you try that?

So, in my reading of the code you would need something like:
`<ldap.authenticate>
<providerUrl>ldap://yourserver.com:389/</providerUrl>
<dn>uid=willian,dc=aqlbras,dc=com</dn>
<password>yourpassword</password>
</ldap.authenticate>`

Comment: I tried this before I post this issue here. The Developer Studio does not allow insert a tag which is not in compliance with the component. If I force it the WSO2 ESB server raise an exception about the unsupported tags.

Comment: I solved the issue. If you want some more details click [here](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-ldap/issues/2).